# link no longer works when included by Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have developed a page that works perfectly when all the HTML is included in a single HTML page. However, now that I've got the page looking and working great, I want to break it out into includes so I can create more pages in the app without having to recreate the menu's and such.

One bit of code is the menu, which includes drop-downs that are activated by  links.

I'm using Custom Directives in Angular JS to break out the includes, so my menu looks something like this:

index.html:

```
<sidebar-standard></sidebar-standard>
```

includes/sidebar-standard.html:

```
<li>
    <a href="javascript:;">my link</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="anotherlink.html">test</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

app.js:

```
app.directive('sidebarStandard', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E', // E = Element Include
        templateUrl: '/includes/sidebar-standard.html'
    };
});
```

This works, and my sidebar gets included, but the javascript drop-down menus no longer function. When I put the HTML directly into index.html, everything works, but when I add it via Angular, it doesn't. There are no errors in the console log.

How would one go about debugging this issue? Any direction anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what does `javascript:;` do? Nothing.. you want like `href=""` ???

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? href=“javascript:;” will do nothing

Comment: Which function is called when you click on the link and the dropdown appears? Is that a jQuery function? If so, that needs to go in your directive

Comment: you have to give your function with it:<a href= javascript:yourFunction()>

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what/how you are controlling the dropdown? jQuery, Bootstrap, another directive? Have you tried adding `replace: true` to your directive. Your `<sidebar-standard>` tag might be messing up the selector you are using to control the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow up on this question, what I had to do was what some of the comments suggested: include the click control function with the directive. After looking over a lot of other people's code, and seeing what the previous author of this app did, I eventually changed from using a directive to using a controller.

So, index.html:

```
<div data-ng-include="'/includes/sidebar-standard.html'" data-ng-controller="SidebarController"></div>
```

app.js

```
app.controller('SidebarController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function() {
        Layout.initSidebar();
    });
}]);
```

Passing the initSidebar() was the key. Thank you guys for pointing the way! Really appreciate the help in research direction. =)